# Electricity causing PC to go slower?

Tags: power-supply, power, desktop-computer

Me and my friend build a PC recently with an 850W EVGA Supernova power supply, Intel core i7 5820k overclocked to 4.5 Ghz, Asus X99 motherboard... . At my place everything was working fine untill he moved his pc to his house, programs and games took like 30 seconds to startup but once a game started up for example everything was running smoothly. We started troubleshooting but couldn't find anything till he moved his pc to his girlfriends house, there we noticed everything was running smoothly again with no issues at all. Once he moved the pc back to his house same problem again, programs taking ages to load

I wonder if it's possible that this has something to do with the electricity at his house? Cause he's living in an old studio.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** Problem solved (check comments)

Comment: I am going to say "no" but I will note that most games require internet connectivity and server negotiation can easily account for this sort of random delay. TCP timeouts are often 30, 60, 90 seconds. If you have other computers saturating the network (read: torrents), this especially likely

Comment: Starting up speccy for example also takes like 30 seconds before the actual window popups

Comment: run resmon at startup and then look at the cpu and disk graphs before and after starting the program.

Comment: Speed is definitely tied to electricity.  With no electricity, you will wait forever for it even to boot up.  :-)

Comment: Most likely it's the Internet connection

Comment: http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/4954364761

Comment: Switched mode power supplies are susceptible to low line voltages; my first computer instead had a constant-voltage linear PSU.  Instead of wondering or guessing, it should be easy to actually ***measure*** this electricity with a multi-meter or a user-friendly power meter such as a [Kill-a-Watt](http://www.p3international.com/products/p4400.html).

Comment: If it really was power related, you could test at different power outlets in that house. A building is normally supplied by a 3-phase-line, so on other outlets you should be connected to a different phase. If the PC runs fast then, you have a serious electric issue. If it is still slow, you should measure voltage. Be careful, can be deadly if done wrong.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss Will contact an electrician to diagnose the problem, If it's indeed an electricity issue. Could this cause hardware damage to the pc itself or will the PSU protect other components? Since the electrician won't be able to come till next week.

Comment: Overvoltage or high voltage peaks can cause damage. Undervoltage normally not. Did you test on other power outlets? The electrician should check the voltage and form of the sinus waves. Electric noise, caused by other switched PSU (not only from PC) or large electric motors (nearby industry) can be an issue.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss Will check other outlets tonight as i'm at work at the moment, Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Different approach: are you using same or different peripherals (Keyboard, mouse, monitor, printer, etc.)? Try the 3 places with always same external hardware and NO network/internet. In general: when testing something, to find out the impact of various factors, change each factor separately. In your case location (power supply) changes, so the rest must stay the same

Comment: After checkup from an electrician everything was fine so started to look more into the network issue like other people started. After disconnecting the network cable the computer was working fine so analysed the network traffic and seemed like Avast was taking lots of bandwidth, we disabled a configuration in Avast that was checking in an online database everytime a program started up. After disabling this everything is running smooth again!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, in theory, if there is bad wiring in his studio and he is not getting a good supply of power from the outlet. You could do a few things to test this out.

1) Get a battery backup and charge it fully at your place then take it to his and run his computer off it. See if the battery backup has to provide supplemental power or if this takes away the slowness.

2) Bring your PC to his place and test that out.

Comment: Thank you, will see if I can obtain a battery backup somewhere and try that out!

Comment: Any computer store or office store like BustBuy and Office Max will have them, will probably run about 30-50$. it is good practice to have a system on a Backup anyways to prevent surge and power outage damage.